# How PHP null comparison will differentiate multiple white-spaces

Tags: php, regex, string, null

I have checked many questions on same topic on stack overflow but still I am not able to do it. Please excuse if I am missing something very trivial.

What I need to check is ...whether a variable does not contain empty(or multiple whitespaces) string ?

but when I use like `$a==NULL`, it will fail for `0` which is a valid string.

when I use `is_null()` or `$a===NULL`, then it will only check for `""` but not if user input contain multiple white space characters like `"     "`.

I guess may be some kind of regular expression may help here but I am not sure. Please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`trim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) to remove whitespace characters:

```
if (trim($my_str) === "") {
    // do things
}
```

Remember to use the [identical comparison operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) whenever possible to avoid truthiness issues (such as `"0"` acting as a false value).

Answer (score 0):

To check if the user submitted a valid string, I'd do this:

```
$str = trim($_POST['submitted_string']);
if(!empty($str)) {
  [...]
}
```